# Apexcharts functionalities are resetted after updateSeries in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apexcharts

I have built a multi-line chart in React. To update the series with new data I use

```
useEffect(() => {
    ApexCharts.exec(chartId, 'updateSeries', data)
}, [data])
```

I use useState for the series

```
const [series, setSeries] = useState([
         {name: 1, data: data1},
         {name: 2, data: data2},
         ...
         ])
```

The Problem:
When I ZOOM IN, ZOOM OUT, DRAG, RESTORE ZOOM, click on HAMBURGER MENU and the series are updated, these functionalities are resetted, for example the hamburger menu closes, the zoom goes to default etc..
Also when I toggle off a serie and the updateSeries is called, the hidden serie comes back to the chart
Is there a way to solve this issue?
Should I create configurations on my own for the chart state?